# Excel - Filter multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, filter

Would anyone be able to help me find a solution on how to filter on multiple worksheets?

What I am trying to achieve is filter the column. when I select "ML" it display what venue he/she was on.

But I would like it to specify what "CREW" number that person was on as shown on the header.

[image]

[image]

The formular that I was using is only work for specific worksheet:

`=BYROW(FILTER(April!Q3:Z97;ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1;April!AB3:AB97));"NO RESULT");LAMBDA(array;INDEX(April!Q1:Z1; MATCH($A$1;array;0))))`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula - adjust the sheet names for `baseData` and `baseCrew` according to your workbook.

```
=LET(baseData,VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),
baseCrew,VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5),
fBaseData,FILTER(baseData,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
fBaseCrew,FILTER(baseCrew,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
HSTACK(fBaseData,BYROW(fBaseCrew,LAMBDA(r,FILTER(April!Q1:Z1,r=$A$1,"no result")))))
```

[image]

The basic trick is to `VSTACK` the two ranges you need for the formula.

I simplified your `BYROW`-formula ...

**Update**

Remove rows with no result

```vb
=LET(baseData,VSTACK(April:May!A2:D5),
baseCrew,VSTACK(April:May!Q2:Z5),
fBaseData,FILTER(baseData,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
fBaseCrew,FILTER(baseCrew,CHOOSECOLS(baseData,1)<>""),
result1,HSTACK(fBaseData,BYROW(fBaseCrew,LAMBDA(r,FILTER(April!Q1:Z1,r=$A$1,"no result")))),
FILTER(result1,CHOOSECOLS(result1,5)<>"no result"))
```

Comment: I have tried this formular and got an error that "first argument of LET must be valid name"

Comment: What's your language? - I just saw that you are using semicolon in your formula - you have to adjust that ...

Comment: My apologies, this formular has worked but how do I eliminate/hide the one with no result?

Comment: add another `Filter` to result ---> see updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this formula is working perfectly, apologies again for a silly answer. I have awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

So I created one formula to get this info, but wouldn't use it myself as it's near impossible to understand and to correct/adjust... The building blocks:

This gives for row 2 the first header where ML is found:

```
=IF(ISERROR(XMATCH("ML";April!Q2:Z2;0));"";INDEX(April!$Q$1:$Z$1;1;XMATCH("ML";April!Q2:Z2;0)))
```

Next, you can create a column for that with BYROW and LAMBDA:

```
=BYROW(April!Q2:AA6;LAMBDA(r;IF(ISERROR(XMATCH("ML";r;0));"";INDEX(April!$Q$1:$Z$1;1;MATCH("ML";r;0)))))
```

Finally, with a FILTER and CHOOSECOLS you can narrow it down to your desired output. Note I only filtered for columns Q, R or S having your ML value:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(April!$A$2:$AA$6;BYROW(April!Q2:AA6;LAMBDA(r;IF(ISERROR(XMATCH("ML";r;0));"";INDEX(April!$Q$1:$Z$1;1;MATCH("ML";r;0))))));(April!Q2:Q6="ML")+(April!R2:R6="ML")+(April!S2:S6="ML"));1;2;3;4;28)
```

If you have multiple sheets, HSTACK might help glue that together...
Had some help from:
https://excelmee.com/excel-formulas/search-a-value-and-return-its-header-in-excel/ ,
https://www.xelplus.com/new-excel-functions-vstack-textsplit-tocol/ and several other sites :-).

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but none of those works because its not only "ML" that I need to search for, the code I originally posted worked but it only allowing me to search 1 sheet, not multiple. I have tried adding 'January:December!' but I get error.